# Как передать обьект между компонентами через сервис

Tags: angular

У меня есть два компонента. Я хочу передать с компонента номер 1 в сервис обьект, а через сервис в другой компонент.

Компонент 1:

```
  getProductInfo( product:any){
  this.clothesService.getProduct(product);
   console.log(product);
   }
```

Сервис:

```
  private infoproduct:Clothes[] = [];


  getProduct(infos:Clothes[]){
     this.infoproduct = infos;

  }
  returnProduct():Clothes[]{
     return this.infoproduct;

  }
```

Компонент 2:

```
constructor(private clothesService:ClothesServiceService) { }
  info:Clothes[] =  [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.info = this.clothesService.getClothes();
  console.log(this.info)
  }
```

Как это сделать, ибо мой вариант не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы передать данные через сервис, можно использовать Subject.

Сервис

```
export class DataStoreService {
  private data = new BehaviorSubject(null); //объявляем subject

  getData$() {
    return this.data; // позволяем получить подписку на эти данные
  }

  setData(data) { // метод для изменения данных
    this.data.next(data);
  }
}
```

Компонент 1

```
export class HelloComponent {
  dataFromService$; // объявляем подписку

  constructor(private dataStore: DtaStoreService) {
    this.dataFromService$ = this.dataStore.getData$(); // получаем доступ к данным сервиса
  }
}
```

Шаблон, подписываемся на изменения через asyncPipe

```
<h1>Hello {{dataFromService$ | async }}!</h1>
```

Компонент 2

```
  changeData() {
    this.dataStore.setData(''someValue);
  }
```

Через метод setData сервиса передаем какие-то данные в сервис. Первый компонент автоматически изменит значение.